# How to make xrdp work with Stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, xrdp

On Jessie, with the Rpi3B, it is simple to enable xrdp:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

badda bing.

---

But with the new Rpi3B+ which requires Stretch, it has a problem.

It will still allow you to get to the login screen, but then after supplying the credentials it then goes to a blank screen.

**How to make xrdp work with Stretch on the new Rpi3B+?**

Answer (score 1):

This is actually unrelated to the new hardware.

Turns out that Stretch comes with RealVNC server installed.  Stretch will run on either 3B or 3B+ systems.  To use VNC, enable it in `raspi-config` and use a RealVNC client for access.

---

But this conflicts with `xrdp`

**To fix the problem and make it work, simply remove RealVNC server.**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge realvnc-vnc-server
```

And voila, RDP access works normally on Stretch.

---